# Twig/Drupal caching and dynamic variables

Tags: 8, caching, theming

I have a template with a list of recent articles and an article itself. I want to check in the list of recent articles if the article currently viewed is there and if yes add a class to the div. This works all fine on a development environment but as soon as I turn on caching it goes haywire. The class is stuck on one item instead of switching to the active one.

How can I solve this?

My template:

```
<a class="news-block {{ node.id == current_id ? 'news-block--active' : '' }}" href="{{ url }}">
    ...
</a>
```

My preprocess:

```
function theme_preprocess_article(array &$variables) {
    $currentNode = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $variables['current_id'] = $currentNode->get('nid')->getValue()[0]['value'];
}
```

Comment: Either do it with JS, or disable page_cache module(for anonymous), or add #cache configuration into the render array(for logged in users).

Comment: Seriously? Editing the #cache didn't work and disabling the page_cache will be an performance issue. I guess it's JS then.

Comment: #cache will have no effect for anonymous users since page_cache module caches the whole pages, whereas dynamic_page_cache caches only parts of pages based on the #cache configuration, but for logged in users only. It depends on your use case. I have implements page cache policy where if certain cookie is present on anonymous user the page_cache is bypassed and dynamic_page_cache takes over.

Comment: Ahh! Do you have an example of editing the #cache configuration?

Comment: Just search for #cache(for example core/modules/book/book.module:241)

Comment: Instead of max age I would use a cache context on the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that this doesn't vary on the same URL, so both page_cache and dynamic_page_cache should be fine. However, each node is also cached on its own, a and that's your problem here.

As 4k4 said in the comment, you should be able to vary the cache with this: `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url'`.

That's rather problematic however, because it means that every node needs to be cached differently on every page, which results in a huge amount of variations that fill up your cache tables.

You could define your own cache context for whether you are on the node page of a given node. Core actually should provide a cache context for that, since it has a similar problem when you'd e.g. use the default view mode somewhere else than on the node/N page. But it doesn't, there's an open issue for that.

As mentioned, the easiest fix is probably to use JS for this.